# Outlook 2016 Rules Turn Off After Restart

Tags: outlook, outlook-2016

I have created rules within outlook 2016 and run well.  However,  when i close outlook and restart my pc.  This rules seem to stopped from work.  And all the emails that has been moved to another folder,  comeback to inbox folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, when i close outlook and restart my pc. This rules seem to stopped from work.

You need to make sure that VBA macros are allowed to run in Trust Center.

> And all the emails that has been moved to another folder, comeback to inbox folder.

It's impossible without any code or user interactions.